# Some comment box wordpress in 1 post

Tags: posts, comments, metabox

Can I add more sections to comment on the same post? For example, I have an Entry and it has 4 tabs, In every tab you need a comments section, Is this possible? Thanks

Comment: What are the "entry" and "tab" precisely?

Comment: The entry is a post... and the post has tabs... example.. http://prntscr.com/5s5uku

Comment: That's how it _looks_, but what it _is_ in technical terms?

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/tabs-shortcode/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible but not exactly trivial or well documented. The easiest option is to have different comment types (ie, have new ones in addition to the traditional comment, pingback and tracback).

The biggest problem with this approach is that most of wordpress API and admin is not built to be flexible enough to sopprt different comments types, for example the recent comments widget might show all type or only one, and it might be hard to style them based on type.

But yes, that design is totally possible just requires more work and some dipper digging into the comments related apis.

Comment: Thanks, if I have been working on this, and I could see that if possible but implementing my own functions and call ... thanks for the tip ...